# Access form data dynamically in symfony 4

Tags: forms, symfony4

I have created following simple form in symfony 4.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('message',TextareaType::class)
    ;
}
```

I access these data from a controller method like following:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class);
$form->handleRequest($request);
$formdata = $form->getData();

$concatenatedData = implode (",", array("Name: ".$formdata['name'], "E-mail: ".$formdata['email'], "Message: ".$formdata['message']));
```

Now i need to add more fields in the form. In that case, I need to loop through the $formdata and get those values in $concatenatedData. I am new in symfony. Can anyone give me any hints how to do that dynamically in symfony 4 ?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use form subscriber to add/modify fields dynamically, Check this [https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html](link)

Comment: No, i can add form fields in buildForm method manually. what i want to do is access those values and fields dynamically. e.g. now i access name fields like "Name: ".$formdata['name']. i want to access those values dynamically

Comment: how can i access form fields and form values from the $formdata dynamically ?

Comment: can u please share the source code of form type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class that you need after defining in form class

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('price');
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Content::class,
    ));
}
}
```

Follow

```
$content = new Content();
$form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $content);
$form->handleRequest($request);
$formdata = $form->getData();

$content->getName();
$content->getOther();
...
```

Comment: here $formdata is an associative array. right ? i need to concatenate those values with field names. how to do that ? using foreach loop ?

Comment: this line $formdata = $form->getData();. it gives an associative array with field name and values. i just need to concatenate those values like $concatenatedData = implode (",", array("field_name1: ".$formdata['value1'], "field_name2: ".$formdata['value2'));

Comment: it does otomaticly matching, form->createView() and using in twig form_start(form) like this

Comment: if i dump $formdata. it shows an associative array. i can use foreach loop to display those data. but i want to concatenate those values like using implode (). how can i do that ?

Comment: maybe it might work for you, dump($form->createView());